# Setting the owner property of a WPF dialog using WindowInteropHelper

Tags: wpf

My WPF user control is hosted in an MFC app. When the UC displays a dialog i want to set the dialogs owner property to be that of the hosting MFC window. So i've got code like this:

```
        1 var configDlg = new ConfigurationDlg();

        2 var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(configDlg) { Owner = mfcParentHwnd };

        3 if (configDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
```

However, if i inspect the configDlg's Owner property at line 3 it's null - so line 2 is seemingly having no effect. BTW mfcParentHwnd is a valid  hwnd being passed in to my UC from the MFC host. Is there some additional work i need to do set my dialogs owner property ?

Comment: well, it seems that the above code does have the desired effect, even though the owner is null i.e. the dlg doesn't display as a secondary window in task manager etc